# listen to an io socket event with an Android client

Tags: android, socket.io

first of all excuse my english, because i am not good in english. I'm looking for a way to retrieve information in android send from a nodeJS server with socket io. I have the impression that it is a problem of version. my code compiles very well, I do not manage to retrieve the information contained in a JS object.
here is the server code

```
 var app = require('express')();
 var http = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);
  var data ={"msg": "hello  i am the server"};

io.on('connection',function(socket){
console.log('one user connected '+socket.id);
socket.on('message',function(obj){

    console.log(obj.text);
      socket.emit('take', data);
  })
socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
 })

 })

 http.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('server listening on port 3000');
  })
```

the information I'm looking for is  'data'

here is the java code I use, I prefer to put the whole code in case the problem is elsewhere

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Socket socket;
public String ReceiveMsg ="message par defaut ";
{
    try {
        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.43.168:3000");
        socket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    socket.connect();
    String msg = takemsg(editText);
    sendMsg(msg);
    socket.on("take", handleIncomingMessages);
    textView.setText(getAz(ReceiveMsg));
    }

   public  String takemsg(EditText editText){
 String msg = "message par defaut ";
msg = editText.getText().toString();
return msg;
}
 public void sendMsg(String msg ){
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  try{
    obj.put("text", msg);
    socket.emit("message", obj);
}catch (JSONException e){
}
 }

private Emitter.Listener handleIncomingMessages = new Emitter.Listener(){
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    ReceiveMsg = data.getString("msg");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think we need more data.

What are the outputs of the server? Is connecting well?, check if your code in android is running.

If it's not connecting try setting the port with opts

```
...
try {
        IO.Options opts = IO.Options();
        opts.port = 3000;
        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.43.168", opts);
        socket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
...
```

check if your service is alive. for services exists some returns that allows to maintain your service working.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I changed the code, now the code compiles on android studio, but my problem is not solved. I manage to send a message to the server, but I do not receive a message from the server. what is the problem on my code

Answer (score 0):

we must put in the manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to allow the application to use the network